# Installing Subclipse 1.8 in Eclipse 3.8

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I am trying to install Sublclipse 1.8 under Eclipse Classic 3.8.2 (M20130131-0800) under OS X 10.8.3. This results in the error message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.9.0.201212170307
```

How can I obtain the missing plugins?

I have set up http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x as an update site, which according to the [Subclipse page](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA) is compatible with Eclipse 3.8. In the install dialog I have selected all the available plugins in both the "Subclipse" and the "SVNKit" group.

Installing GEF from the update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno does not work either:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv,3.8.1.201212170307
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.draw2d.sdk,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d.source,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.draw2d.source,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv,3.8.1.201212170307
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.ui.pde,3.8.1.201212170307
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef.sdk,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.source,3.9.0.201212170307
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef.source,3.9.0.201212170307
```

Comment: Please give additional details about how you try to install it: from which update site or from Marketplace etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Subversion Revision Graph optional feature needs GEF, so if it is not necessary for you, you can skip installing it. Otherwise, things to try:

- Install Subclipse simply from Marketplace, as the [Installation Instructions](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA) suggest. (If your distribution doesn't contain it, you can install Marketplace itself from the Juno update site.)
- The Juno update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno contains GEF, make sure it is among your available software sites. You can also try the GEF milestone update site: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/milestones

Comment: Installing GEF from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/milestones/ finally worked. The Marketplace is not available by default in Eclipse Classic. Anyway working with plug-ins in Eclipse is always such a pain in the neck.

Comment: You can add the Eclipse Marketplace Client to Eclipse Classic.  Just expand what is in the Juno repository and it is one of the things you can add.